# redis high response time when searching with regex

Tags: node.js, regex, caching, redis

I use redis for my main database(mongodb) caching system.
everything works fine until cached documents count getting larger, for example after 15K document cached, redis response time increasing.

this is my **key**, **value** in Redis

```
key: userId_123_username_test_email_test@gmail.com
value: JSON.stringfy(userobject)
```

as i said in title when i trying to find documents with regex, response time increasing.

> i looking for indexing document and i found this [article](https://redis.io/topics/indexes)

according this article i found that i can set index for age field but actually i need to set index for email or username

```
HMSET user:1 id 1 username antirez ctime 1444809424 age 38
ZADD user.age.index 38 1
```

also try this:

```
ZADD user.username.index antirez 1
```

return error: 
 *ERR value is not a valid float*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ERR value is not a valid float` is because:

> The score values should be the string representation of a double precision floating point number. +inf and -inf values are valid values as well.

So you should not use the email or username in sortedset value, you could try another method to build the secondary index: **Lexicographical indexes**, which also mentioned in the your mentioned article.

In this method, just set the value to 0 and using the member's lex order to build the index. E.g. if you want to build the index for username :

```
ZADD user.username.index 0 antirez:1
```

So when you want to find the id which its name is antirez, you could do this:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX user.username.index [antirez + limit 1 1
```

the `[` means inclusive, the `+` means infinite big, and it will only return one member, e.g. antirez:1, then you split the string by colon, you will get the id of antirez. Email sames as username.

**UPDATE For comment:**

YES, you could make something like **composite indexes** likes relational database.  But it also need to have an order, like (username, ctime, ...).

E.g. If you want to build a composite indexes with username and ctime:

```
ZADD user.composite.index 0 antirez:2017-09-04:1
```

When you want to get the id with username and ctime:

```
ZRANGEBYLEX user.composite.index [antirez:2017-09-04 (antirez:2017-09-05
```

It will return all ids in this period and its username is antirez.

In conclusion, you could using sortedset to build an index like rdb's index.

if the index is (key1,key2,key3), then you should set the prefix of member to "key1:key2:key3:" and then add a ref value or real value to this string like:
"key1:key2:key3:ref_value", and set all member's value to equal. SortedSet will order all members by their lex order, so you could use a prefix of composite indexes to index such as : key1, key1:key2 or key1:key2:key3.

As for store with ref value or real value , maybe ref_value is more flexible, you could store the real value in other data type, it can be list or hash or set. When you want to update something, you could first using the secondary index to fetch its ref_value, and then go to its real_value to change it.

Comment: it's worked when i change `ZRANGEBYLEX user.username.index [antirez + limit 0 1`, thank you ♥

Comment: is there any way to find with two or more than two indexes, for example i want some thing like this `ZRANGEBYLEX user.username.index [antirez + limit 0 1 user.ctime.index [1444809424 + limit 0 1` and also i index **both** of them (username, ctime)

Comment: it's work but actually i need find with not sorted indexes something like this: (uname, email, ctime) or (email, ctime, uname,...) or another

Comment: What is the difference bettween the ` (uname, email, ctime) ` and ` (email, ctime, uname,...)`, you could order this by your specified order, and then they will be same.

Comment: maybe sometimes i don't have email then i should find with (uname, ctime), is this valid `ZRANGEBYLEX user.composite.index [uname:email + limit 0 1` for this composite index `ZADD user.composite.index 0 uname:email:ctime`

Comment: IN this case, your should set the order to be (uname, ctime, email), then you can find with first two keys, zadd should be like `ZADD user.composite.index 0 uname:ctime:email:id` with find `ZRANGEBYLEX user.composite.index [uname:ctime + limit 0 1` if you don't have email key.

Answer (score 1):

```
return error: ERR value is not a valid float is because the order is wrong
Try zadd user.username.index 1 antirez

127.0.0.1:6379> zadd user.username.index 1 antirez 
Response: (integer) 1

127.0.0.1:6379> zrange user.username.index 0 -1 withscores
```

1) "antirez"

2) "1"

```
127.0.0.1:6379>
```